# Laravel eloquent get one array of two dimensional arrays

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here my code :

```
$classroom_ids = $user->classrooms->pluck('id');
            $classrooms = Classroom::with('students')
                ->whereIn('id', $classroom_ids)
                ->get();
```

I try to get all cumulated students on twos classrooms records.

I tried to use ->pluck('students') without success.

Here the classrooms datas :

```
0 => [
  'id' : 1,
  'students': Array of students
],
1 => [
  'id' : 2,
  'students': Array of students
],
```

How to get all students in one array ? Thanks

Comment: please show your models and relationships

Comment: I think your query base model should be of Student instead of Classroom like 
`Student::whereIn('class_id', $user->classroom->pluck('id'))->get()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use map with flatten.

```
$classrooms = Classroom::with('students')
            ->whereIn('id', $classroom_ids)
            ->get()
            ->map(function($classroom){
                return $classroom->students;
            })
            ->flatten()
            ->toArray();
```

If students to classroom is a many to many you can use keyBy there are no duplicates.

```
$classrooms = Classroom::with('students')
            ->whereIn('id', $classroom_ids)
            ->get()
            ->map(function($classroom){
                return $classroom->students;
            })
            ->flatten()
            ->keyBy('id')
            ->toArray();
```

Comment: [flatMap](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-flatmap) if you please :)

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution (inspired by Jed Lynch answer) :

```
$classroom_ids = $user->classrooms->pluck('id');
            $users = Classroom::with('students')
                ->whereIn('id', $classroom_ids)
                ->get()
                ->pluck('students')
                ->flatten();
```

Thank's for your help !